# MySQLBulkLoader not inserting any row in mysql db

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkloader

```
   var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(mycon);
            bl.TableName = "tblspmaster";
            bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
            bl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
            bl.FileName = "E://31october//SP//sp_files_sample1//400k sp00 6-19 E.csv";
            bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;

            var inserted = bl.Load();
```

I am using this code to upload a csv file in db but its not  throwing any exception and inserted always show zero .

**dotnetconnector for mysql is already installed and reference is also added .**

Comment: Why the double slashes in the path? Only backslash should need that treatment.

Comment: I changed double slashes into single slashes . Its working now but i don't understand why its only inserting one row. Might be issue with my csv as when i open that csv into notepad then there will be no commas.

Comment: Are you sure the line terminator is `"\r\n"` and not `"\n"`?

Comment: i have used another approach and its works for me similar to this. I used following c# code. string sql = @"load data infile 'E:/31october/SP/sp_files_sample1/a1.csv' ignore into table tblspmaster fields terminated by '' enclosed by '' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (sp)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000000;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have used this code and its working for me

```
string sql = @"load data infile 'E:/a1.csv' ignore into table tblspmaster fields terminated by '' enclosed by '' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (sp)";
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon); 
cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000000; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not insert the data, if your csv file and the mysql table columns are not matched.
For example if your mysql table has a primary key column with identity key, and generally you won't have this column in csv file.

So in the above case the mysqlloader will not insert the data.
To solve this use columns property and add the columns mysql table column names

here is a sample code.

```
public async Task<bool> MySqlBulkLoaderAsync(string csvFilePath)
    {
        bool result = true;
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_connString + ";AllowLoadLocalInfile=True"))
            {
                var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn)
                {
                    TableName = "patientdetailstagings",
                    Timeout = 600,
                    FieldTerminator = ",",
                    LineTerminator = "\n",
                    FieldQuotationCharacter = '"',
                    FileName = csvFilePath,
                    NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1
                };
                bl.Columns.AddRange(new List<string>() {"Column1", "Column2"});
                var numberOfInsertedRows = await bl.LoadAsync();
            }
            System.IO.File.Delete(csvFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Note: the column mapping will be done based on the way you have added them in the columns property.
In the same order it will access the column value from csv file